# C# Index was outside the bounds of the array while generating Json objects

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a class:

```
internal class Movie
{
    public class BaseResponse
    {
        public Item[] search { get; set; }
        public string response { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string title { get; set; }            
    }
```

I want to create n objects for search array like this:

```
public void Generate()
{
   Movie.BaseResponse baseResponse = new Movie.BaseResponse();
   baseResponse.response = "True!";

   baseResponse.search = new Movie.Item[] { new Movie.Item()};
   baseResponse.search[0].title = "Title one";
   baseResponse.search[1].title = "Title two"; //Error accurs here****

   string response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(baseResponse);
}
```

but this script does not work right and it gives the following error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

Can anyone explain how can I create n objects of `search` array in the `Movie` class?

Comment: `baseResponse.search = new Movie.Item[] { new Movie.Item()};` only defines one item in the array, so `[1]` throws the error. If you want more, add more `new Movie.Item()` calls inside the brackets.

Comment: @RonBeyer: as I said, I need to create n objects. for example I cannot add 'new Movie.Item()' for 100 times. is there any way to create objects without defining the counts?

Comment: You _need to create n objects_, so use a loop, what's the question here? You created an array with item, if you need to create an array with _n_ items use a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using an array (`T[]`), you may be better off using a `List<T>`.  You need to know how many items will be in an array up front (since they get allocated contiguously).  You can add new items to a List at any time.

Changing your code:

```
internal class Movie
{
    public class BaseResponse
    {
        public List<Item> Search { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
        public string Response { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }            
    }
}


public void Generate()
{
   Movie.BaseResponse baseResponse = new Movie.BaseResponse();
   baseResponse.Response = "True!";

   baseResponse.Search.Add (new Movie.Item { Title = "Title One" }); 
   baseResponse.Search.Add (new Movie.Item { Title = "Title Two" }); 

   string response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(baseResponse);
}
```

That seems to work.  I get this as `response`:

```
{
    "Search":[
        {"Title":"Title One"},
        {"Title":"Title Two"}],
     "Response":"True!"
}
```

Comment: can you please clarify, How can I use List<T> instead of 'public string search' inside the 'Movie' Class?

Comment: @E.Mamaghani. there you go.  `List<T>` is almost always better than an array of T.

Answer (score 1):

You've create an array with 1 item, but you're trying to access the non-existent second item.

Change the relevant line to something like:

```
baseResponse.search = new Movie.Item[] { new Movie.Item(), new Movie.Item() };
```

Comment: as I said, I need to create n objects. for example I cannot add 'new Movie.Item()' for 100 times. is there any way to create objects without defining the counts?